# Build only the Git branch that has been pushed to

Tags: git, github, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a Jenkins job to build the `master` branch of my GitHub repo. It triggers nicely when I push a commit to `master`, and I'm very happy about it.

I would also like to have a single Jenkins job that would build any other branch in this repository. I.e. whenever I push a commit to a branch (that is not `master`), I'd like to have this Jenkins job to build that branch, and only that branch.

Using the GitHub pull-request plugin requires me to create a pull-request, and merges my commit with `master`. I'd like to do this without having to create a pull-request, and to only build my commit without merging it with `master`.

Setting up the Git plugin to build all branches means that whenever I push to master, all branches are built. I'd like to only build the one branch that has been modified.

Is this possible to do in Jenkins?

Comment: By default in Jenkins, you specify the single branch you want to be built.  I am unclear what you mean when you say, "whenever I push to master, all branches are built"

Comment: have you tried the [Jenkins Github plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/GitHub+Plugin#GitHubPlugin-TriggerabuildwhenachangeispushedtoGitHub)?

Comment: @JosephDeCarlo: Added some clarification to the question: I'd like to have a single job to build the branches (just as I have a single job to build `master`). @AesSedai101: I'm not sure what you mean by using the GitHub plugin. I'm already using it to trigger on push to repo.

Comment: I have not used jenkins yet but had some success for similar requirement with Travis. If you are interested in knowing about that I will share, In the meantime I will look into jenkins....

Comment: @LórántPintér based on the up-votes so far, would you mind marking my answer below as the correct one?

Answer (score 15):

I was having the same issue so I set up a dummy project to experiment and found the solution. And found that yes, you *can* build only the branch that's been pushed into.

The short answer is to use a **"Branch Specifier"**. For instance `origin/feature**`.

If you're using the [GitFlow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow) and all your feature branches are named with a `feature/` prefix, then this is the solution.

And if you're curious here's how I figured it out.

From the repository's settings I set the service **“Github plugin”** with the Jenkins hook `https://<jenkin server>/github-webhook/`.
Note that, at least for me what happened was that for some reason after pressing ***"test"***, the message of the payload being sent never changed to confirm it was received/acknowledged or anything. Maybe there’s no reply. It's confusing, but anyway...

I created a new Jenkins job and set the ***branch specifier*** to ***blank*** -which Jenkins then automatically sets to `**`.

I created a feature branch `feature/foo` and pushed into it.

- Build 1 was fired, but on the `master` branch.
- Build 2 was also fired on the `feature/foo` branch.

So it seems with the `**` or blank specifier the plugin will fire builds on all branches of a repo whenever there’s a push to *any* of them.

Then I tried with pattern `refs/heads/feature/foo` and pushed another change to the `feature/foo` branch.

- Build 3 was fired on the `feature/foo` branch.
- No other builds were fired.

Sort of ok, but this is too rigid. It would force us to have one build job for each feature branch. I wanted one build job for *all* feature branches.

Then I tried a wildcard with pattern `refs/heads/feature\*\*` and pushed changes to `feature/foo`.

- No build was fired.

Then I tried branch specifier `refs/heads/feature/\*\*` and pushed.

- No build was fired

Then I saw the help of the ***"Branch Specifier"*** field reads this under the "Wildcards" section:

> The syntax is of the form: `REPOSITORYNAME/BRANCH`. In addition, `BRANCH` is recognized as a shorthand of `*/BRANCH`, `*` is recognized as a wildcard, and `**` is recognized as wildcard that includes the separator `/`. Therefore, `origin/branches*` would match `origin/branches-foo` but not `origin/branches/foo`, while `origin/branches**` would match both `origin/branches-foo` and `origin/branches/foo`.

So I tried `origin/feature**`

- Build 4 was fired on `origin/feature/foo`.

Eureka! Seems you can’t use wildcards with the references (starting with `refs/`), but you *can* with the names of the actual branches (starting with `origin/`).

Then I created branch `feature/bar` and pushed to it. To verify that only this one would be built and not other branches also starting with `feature/`.

- Build 5 was fired on `origin/feature/bar`.

Looked almost there. Just needed a few more tests.

Then I pushed another change to `origin/master`

- No build fired. Great!

Then I pushed another change to `feature/bar`, to test that only this branch would be built. Despite the fact that `origin/master` had also been pushed into.

- Build 6 was fired on `feature/bar`.
- No other builds fired.

Looks good to me.

Comment: When you say "build," what do you mean? A specific Jenkins job, or the running of one job? So like when you say Build 1 and 2 were fired at first, are you saying the same job was run twice? How could a build for `master` run when you pushed to `feature/foo`?

Comment: @redOctober13 by *build* I mean a job execution/run. So yes, when I leave the branch specifier blank or set it to `**` and push to any one branch, then the same job runs xN times, once for each branch. This of course is not ideal, hence all the testing that led me to the conclusion that `origin/feature**` is the correct branch specifier to use.

Comment: @Mig82 OK. so how do you build only a single branch (say branch-1235) if you don't have any naming conventions?

Answer (score 4):

You can see there plugin of multiple branch configuring with Jenkins. Getting feedback for any branch from Jenkins is possible with that method.

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multi-Branch+Project+Plugin

I hope it may help.

Comment: This answer should be sufficient.

Comment: I agree with this, the multi-branch plugin should be what your using.

Comment: It'd be nice to have more detail on exactly how this plugin solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Found there's an `whitelist` config listed in `Build Trigger` section:

[image: click advanced to expand all options]

[image: whitelist]

There you can specify to build/test which branch the PR will be merged into.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there seems to be an answer to precisely this question on the Jenkins GitHub plugin page :

[Trigger a build when a change is pushed to GitHub](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/GitHub+Plugin#GitHubPlugin-TriggerabuildwhenachangeispushedtoGitHub)

Comment: The `GitHub plugin` runs the Jenkins job no matter which branch is pushed to GitHub.

Comment: Yes. Like Tim Murhpy said: there is no info, regarding to issue raised in this question.

Answer (score 0):

As @thatway_3 [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29393361/328817), this is possible with a plugin.  The Multi-Branch Project Plugin that they linked to is deprecated, but you can use the [Pipeline Multibranch Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Multibranch+Plugin) instead.

If you install that plugin and then create a new job of type "Pipeline Multibranch", you can configure that to track a particular repository.  It will then (correctly!) build all branches from there.

See also: https://jenkins.io/blog/2015/12/03/pipeline-as-code-with-multibranch-workflows-in-jenkins/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -4):

you can easily specify branch in job configuration:

in section **Source Code Management** where you have already specified your git repository URL you have also an option to specify **branches to build**. Simply please a name of your branch instead of master (which is default value).

Comment: The idea is to leave this field empty.. and the build should know which branch was pushed