# Jenkins build only one branch that has been pushed

Tags: git, github, jenkins, webhooks

I'd like to config Jenkins that build only one branch has been pushed to github. I tried [with leave blank at   Branch Specifier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mm10q.png)

But after I committed/pushed all branches will be built. I just need only one branch has just been committed/pushed to be built.
How can I do that?
Thanks.

Comment: Did you found any solution for this?

Comment: No, I didn't. @UmarQureshi

Comment: This question already has an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39884629/4124574

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Build only the Git branch that has been pushed to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27403576/build-only-the-git-branch-that-has-been-pushed-to)

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider the [pipelines](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/) triggered by external hooks? If github support hooks (I don't know it) you can do something like below in post-receive hook. This will run the job only if the code was pushed to the development branch.

```
while read oldrev newrev ref
do
    if [[ $ref =~ .*/development$ ]];
    then
            curl -s http://jenkins:8080/job/stage/build
            echo Jenkins pipeline triggered by calling the webservice
    fi
done
```